# Comparing two consecutive rows in the table and ignoring the results if the condition is fulfilled

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have one problem with comparing values in a table in MSSQL database.

One column (let's say it's called ID) contains integer values - those values are supposed to be consecutive. The other column contains location ID info. Now there is one other column that contains info whether the product has failed quality check (binary value - 0 or 1).

Now what I am trying to do is to compare two consecutive rows, find out if values in ID column are consecutive as well and select those location IDs which haven't got consecutive values in ID columns only IF quality check column has value 0. If it is 1 I want my query to sort of jump to the next row and compare the next row with the previous one.

So to sum it up I want to select only those locationIDs from the table which do not have consecutive ID values for quality check set at 0 (if its 1 and not consecutive - ignore the result)

I was thinking about using cursor for this one but I am not quite sure, I would highly appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction (preferably with some example). Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  And what does `locationId` have to do with `id`?

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers, e.g. `Lead`/`Lag`. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `lag()`.  I think it is something like this:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id,
             lag(info) over (order by id) as prev_info
      from t
     ) t
where id <> prev_id + 1 and prev_info = 0 and info = 0;
```

This returns the row following the gap.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(id) over (order by id) as prev_id
      from t
      where info = 0
     ) t
where id > prev_id + 1 
order by id
```